# Appending a list in a dictionary with a value of index of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary and a list:

```
results = {"Alice":[], "Bob":[], "Clare":[], "Dennis":[], "Eva":[]}
list_of_names = ['Bob', 'Alice', 'Clare', 'Eva', 'Dennis']
```

and I want to fill those lists with a value of index+1 accordingly.
So that if we have the list above the dictionary would look like this

```
results = {"Alice":[2], "Bob":[1], "Clare":[3], "Dennis":[5], "Eva":[4]}
```

this is my current code

```
Aindex = list_of_names.index("Alice")
Bindex = list_of_names.index("Bob")
Cindex = list_of_names.index("Clare")
Dindex = list_of_names.index("Dennis")
Eindex = list_of_names.index("Eva")
Aindex = Aindex + 1
Bindex = Bindex + 1
Cindex = Cindex + 1
Dindex = Dindex + 1
Eindex = Eindex + 1
results["Alice"].append(Aindex)
results["Bob"].append(Bindex)
results["Clare"].append(Cindex)
results["Dennis"].append(Dindex)
results["Eva"].append(Eindex)
```

Is there any way to shorten this code and make it work for any amount of dictionary/list entries?

Comment: `for i, x in enumerate(list_of_names): results[name].append(i+1)` ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes. One line with dictionary comprehension and `enumerate` starting at 1:

```
list_of_names = ['Bob', 'Alice', 'Clare', 'Eva', 'Dennis']

results = {name:[i] for i,name in enumerate(list_of_names,1)}


>>> results
{'Alice': [2], 'Bob': [1], 'Clare': [3], 'Dennis': [5], 'Eva': [4]}
```

Comment: Never knew that you could specify a starting position for `enumerate`. Good stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the existing list inside the dict

```
results = {"Alice":[], "Bob":[], "Clare":[], "Dennis":[], "Eva":[]}
list_of_names = ['Bob', 'Alice', 'Clare', 'Eva', 'Dennis']
for i,j in enumerate(list_of_names,1):
    results[j].append(i)
```